# Why is Petyr Baelish called "Littlefinger"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Petyr Baelish is constantly referred to as "Littlefinger," and some mention that he doesn't like this name.

The first thing that comes to mind is that it's because he is not physically well-equipped, but I doubt that's the real reason.

What is the backstory behind his nickname?

Comment: Incidentally, this is your second question about *Game of Thrones* where the answer is something that's not been on the TV show but is in the books. There's a *lot* of stuff like that. If you're interested in the series to this extent, you should just go and read the books.

Comment: @MikeScott indeed, but : 1 - My to read stack is full, 2 - I ask this for the benefit of the community (I'm not the only one who didn't read the book yet) 3 - It's [Game of Thrones Week](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1138/45)!

Comment: @AndresF. Why are the show viewer treated in such condescending way by the books readers?

Comment: @DavRob60 I was half-joking. But it's not about TV vs books; this is a pet peeve with scifi.se in general: people asking questions which can be answered by simply watching (or reading) the movie (or book). It's like the _ultimate_ laziness. You want to know how Harry Potter ends? Read the book instead of asking about it on the net! Probably no-one else on scifi.se will agree with me on this, so I'll stop my rant here.

Comment: @DavRob60 By the way, to show this is not my prejudice against show viewers: Littlefinger's nickname _has also been explained in the show_.

Comment: @AndresF. It's not everybody who have perfect memory and could cite the exact word of a sci-fi works. And, with almost 9k views, I'm not the only one who missed it when it was explained.

Comment: Lots of lazy people on the internet :) (Just look at the average question on SO). Anyway, I don't expect you to agree with me on this, but I hope I have shown it wasn't prejudice against show viewers as much as against lazy people :P

Comment: @AndresF. Questions that can be answered by "simply" reading the entire Game of Thrones series of novels? Come on...

Comment: @user202930 No, you merely need to make the effort to read *some* of "A Game of Thrones", the first book in the series -- page 167 to be exact. I dislike this kind of questions because they are like the ultimate form of laziness. And, by the way, *this question is also answered in episode 4 of the TV show*, so the OP cannot bother to read the books or watch the TV show. Let me call this Extreme All-Encompassing Laziness :)

Comment: Well, I just found a new nickname for someone else...

Comment: How is forgetting a small detail in a 5000 page book series, and then being unable to find it and unwilling to reread the whole thing just for that purpose, "the ultimate form of laziness".....?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The Fingers are rocky peninsulae near the Vale of Arryn, and Petyr's father was the lord of the smallest of them. And he is relatively short of stature, both as an adult and as a child when he was given the nickname.

He doesn't like this nickname as it points out he's just a minor lord and pretty much mocks him for being short sized.

Quoting directly from "A Game of Thrones" by George RR Martin;

> Catelyn’s mouth grew tight. “Littlefinger,” she murmured. His face
>   swam up before her; a boy’s face, though he was a boy no longer. His
>   father had died several years before, so he was Lord Baelish now, yet
>   still they called him Littlefinger. Her brother Edmure had given him
>   that name, long ago at Riverrun. His family’s modest holdings were on
>   the smallest of the Fingers, and Petyr had been slight and short for
>   his age.

Comment: FWIW - Edmure Tully gave him the name while Peter was a Tully ward in his youth. Game of Thrones, chapter 18 (Catelyn), pg 167 US paperback edition.

Answer (score 7):

Moreover, answer can be found in series as well. Petyr tells it to Arya and Sansa while watching a joust (episode 4 I think) where The Mountain kills ser Hugh.

Answer (score 4):

On page 167 of Game of Thrones (the first book), it says:

> Her brother Edmure had given him that name, long ago at Riverrun. His family's modest holdings were on the smallest of the Fingers, and Petyr had been slight and short for his age.

Answer (score 3):

Petyr Baelish is known as ‘Littlefinger’, a nickname he was given by Edmure Tully when Petyr was his ward. The name refers to the old seat of the House of Baelish, which sits on one of the smallest fingers of land that reach out into the Narrow Sea from the Vale of Arryn

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is right, only missing the second interpretation of the nickname.

Answer (score 1):

Vit Michael has it right.

But, the books and the show both refer to Littlefinger's *finger being little* often enough, that it might be true.

Obviously, Littlefinger is going to tell his "I was short and from the Fingers" story, rather than "I'm physically lacking *downstairs*" (especially to a 10 year old girl).

Edmure might have just come up with a very clever nickname that mocks Baelish in more than one way.